# How could I display a type="color" input as a circle?

Tags: html, css

I have a form with a lot of color inputs. I am using boostrap and the default look for a color input is horrible so I have been adding my own CSS on top of it to clean it up. I have gotten rid of the big white border but now I would like to have it display as a circle instead of a square. I would like it to be a flat circle with no border and maybe even with a slight shadow for a material design-esque look.

This is one of my color inputs:

```
<div class="col-xs-1 menu-title-color-div color-input-div">
  <input type="color" id="menu-title-color-input"
         class="form-control menu-data color-input menu-title-color-input"
         name="MenuTitleColor">
</div>
```

and the CSS I am using to gain the look. (When I figure out how to display them as a circle I am going to move this CSS to a more specific css selector)

```
.form-control {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 0;    
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Here is what it looks like so far.  There also still seems to be a thin, gray border around the inputs but I can't figure out how to get rid of that either.

[image]

[github](https://github.com/dylanrdrake/ez-menu)

Comment: Your selector may not have enough specificity to override the styles from the previous sheet.  Check the console to see what is being applied, what file, and the selector is that targets those elements.

Comment: I tried to apply a radius and border-radius on a input[type="color"] selector but it still doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I am understanding you correctly - you want those three buttons to be circles instead of squares? Or do  you want the whole div to be a square?

Either way, this is one option of doing it by manipulating the radius and setting a width and height:

```
.form-control {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: inherit;
  padding: 0;    
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
width: 100%;
height:100%;
border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Comment: The colored squares are color inputs. I want them to display as circles instead of squares.

Comment: Ok I get it.  So give them a definitive width and height and add a "background-color:" and you should be good!

Comment: It's not working.  I created a new html file with just a basic, no bootstrap color input and tried this but it still does not work.

Comment: can you post the exact css div for the squares and I can tell you?

Comment: I added the github repo to the original post. the css file is  frontend/style.css

Comment: It's ```border-radius``` not ```radius```.